# CMake для C-проекта

Tags: c, cmake, makefile

Собственно нужен ли Cmake для голого С проекта, ибо в репозитории Linux обходятся простым make? А на форумах бородатые кодеры говорят, что в Cmake много лишнего и ненужного.

Comment: настоящие бородатые хакеры даже компилятор не используют. А CMake и подавно:)

Comment: перефразируя чехова, супротив мэйка симэйк всё равно, что плотник супротив столяра. это совершенно разные программы для совершенно разных целей. мэйк — универсальный интепрератор (язык программ для него, вроде бы, тьюринг полный), а симэйк — узкоспециализированный конфигуратор и генератор программ для того же мэйка.

Comment: Да и в make много лишнего и ненужного. Например крякозяберные макросы и встроенные правила.

Comment: ninja или баш скрипты?

Comment: @VTT, нет в мэйке ненужного. иначе на нём не решить задачу [«в своём ли уме валет?»](http://www.cyberforum.ru/prolog/thread985851.html). а решение [таки есть](https://gist.github.com/sash-kan/3377201).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin [Но зачем](https://www.linux.org.ru/images/16134/original.jpg)?

Comment: @VTT, ссылка на gist — это моё решение конкурсной задачи по функциональному программированию от августа 2012. [список задач](http://haskell98.blogspot.com/2013/01/2011.html) есть, но сами задачи darcus, видимо, увы, грохнул вместе со своей уютненькой жежешечкой. впрочем, можно попробовать их отрыть на [архив.орг](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://users.livejournal.com/-darkus-/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вам уже сказали в комментариях, единого ответа на ваш вопрос нет, так как деталей слишком мало, а программы рассчитаны на несколько разное. Ниже просто перечисляю то, с чем сталкивался сам, сравнивая Make и CMake для сборки и поддержки проектов.

*Всё нижеперечисленное исключительно ИМХО.*

Преимущества Make:

- Простой и понятный.
- Больше контроля.
- Проверенный временем.
- Быстрый (если не извращаться).
- Не создаёт 100500 временных файлов.

Недостатки Make перед CMake:

- Менее переносимый (скрипты для GNU Make могут не завестись на ванильном POSIX Make, про Windows забудьте).
- Больше бойлерплейта (но у CMake за счёт большого количества "удобных" функций сложность намного выше).
- Сложнее устраивать юнит-тестирование (у CMake встроенная поддержка).

Для персональных проектов в итоге всегда выбираю Make. Если придётся делать большой публичный проект на C/C++, видимо воспользуюсь CMake.